# Нанесение текста на картинку с переносом строк по границе области

Tags: c#, winforms, текст

Сейчас есть только такое решение:

```
Image a = Image.FromFile("D://test.jpg");
Graphics part2 = Graphics.FromImage(a);
part2.DrawString("aaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaa aaa aaa aaaaa aaaaaaa",
        new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Bold),
        new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new RectangleF(0, 0, 0, 340),
        new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap));
a.Save("D://imgres.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Но хотелось бы узнать, как сделать перенос строки по границе `RectangleF`.

Оригинальное изображение:
[image: оригинальное изображение]

Изображение, которое получается сейчас:

[image: текущее изображение]

Comment: Не ручаюсь за правильность, но когда-то вроде делал так: `string str = @first (здесь просто нажать Enter) second...";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (var image = Image.FromFile(source))
{
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        var textBounds = graphics.VisibleClipBounds;
        textBounds.Inflate(-5, -5);

        graphics.DrawString(
            "aaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaa aaa aaa aaaaa aaaaaaa",
            SystemFonts.CaptionFont,
            Brushes.Red,
            textBounds
        );
    }

    image.Save(result);
}
```

Результат:

[image: результат]

Т.е. тупо уберите аргумент `new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap)`, который собственно и запрещает переносы. Текст переносится по умолчанию.

Comment: Оо, я просто делал до этого вообще без флагов, не хотело переносить. Действительно работает, спасибо огромное :)